# How to acces checkBox and filter data

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have my xaml page with check boxes that should filter a list whether it is checked or not.

I need the list to be filtered based on   but I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone please point me the right direction?

Comment: To filter your list based on the check boxes, I think is better you bind the IsChecked property to a boolean defined in your viewmodel. And then, you can check the status of your checkbox and perform the needed action. In addtion, what is the role of _parentCategoryId ?

Comment: That triggered the action thanks. Well parentId is the id of category and should be filtered based on the parent id

Comment: I need to filter the list of  articles for purchase with that parent id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter the list, you can do this:

```
var result = FilterArticlesForPurchase.Where(x => x.YourParentCategoryId == _parentCategoryId).ToList();
```